# Excel - Get Textbox value that calls macro

Tags: excel, vba

I do a lot of remote IT support and made a map of all the computers in my building in textboxes. I wanted to be able to click on the relevant computer and have it open the remote viewing program.

I found this code elsewhere on this site

```
Sub Auto_Open()
    Dim x As Variant
    Dim Path As String


    ' Set the Path variable equal to the path of your program's installation
    Path = """W:\Remote\CmRcViewer.exe"" ""PC13054"""

    x = Shell(Path, vbNormalFocus)
 End Sub
```

I was wondering if there is a way to pull the textbox.value of the textbox that calls the macro dynamically? Such as this.value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to rename all the text boxes to the name of the machine that they represent. Then assign all the text boxes to this procedure.

```
Option Explicit

Sub openRemoteViewer()

    Dim whichMachine As String
    whichMachine = Application.Caller

    Dim path As String
   ' Set the Path variable equal to the path of your program's installation
    path = """W:\Remote\CmRcViewer.exe"" """ & whichMachine & """"

    Dim x As Variant
    x = Shell(path, vbNormalFocus)

 End Sub
```

There are other ways, but I think this may be the easiest to implement.